# Finding the API using reflection from the server & using it like NancyFx

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, nancy

From what I understand NancyFX uses Reflection to find classes that extend NancyModule, and then it can use those classes and make the http calls through them.

I've managed to get the class I'm looking for from the server class using reflection:

```cs
public static void Register(string ass1, string ass2)
{
    Assembly assembly1 = Assembly.Load(ass1);
    Assembly assembly2 = Assembly.Load(ass2);
    Assembly[] assemblies = { assembly1, assembly2 };

    foreach (var assembly in assemblies)
    {
        var types = assembly.GetExportedTypes();

        if (!(assembly.GetExportedTypes().Length > 10))
        {
            foreach (var type in types)
            {
                if (type.BaseType != null)
                {
                    var a = type.BaseType.Name;
                    if (type.BaseType.Name == "ApiController")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("YES");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am still not sure what to return in this method, the Type, the name, I'll deal with that later, for now I want to understand what is next? What is the next step?

Comment: Imagine you have a self hosted server in one solution, and your ApiController in anothet one, how would you reach that Api from your server?

Comment: Someone told me that you need to find the api class using reflection & then put him in a container but thats way too abstract for me to understand

Comment: Oh, you write them ,. Its your own api class just not running on a web server.

Comment: With nancy you can :  Use nancy self host to host a server and use its TinyIocContainer for the DI. Then in another solution instead of using controllers you write a class that extends NancyModule, you use nancy syntax for methods & paths then when you run the server nancy automaticlly detects classes that extend the NancyModule.